# VB.NET - Hide warning error dll not present

Tags: vb.net

is it possible in VB.NET to remove the warning message when the dll is not present in the directory?

[DLL Present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrkuS.jpg)

[DLL NOT Present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmKV6.jpg)

I want to save this error in the txt file and I don't want to display the error on the screen when it is not there. it's possible ?

Comment: What error? What dll? Is the dll needed by the program?

Comment: Do you know when you import a dll?  The program needs that dll.  If it is not present in the folder, you will get an error message that cannot be loaded.  I would like the error returned to me in a .txt file.  I tried with a try catch by inserting the method inside but it doesn't work.

Comment: Update your question with your attempt at handling the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.